# Auto click in 5 minute intervals

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to create a script that will, when toggled, click the specified areas of the screen at 5 minute intervals. I have got the 'mouseclick' functions working fine, but I am struggling to utilise the loop function (if I need it it all) and am not sure if the SetTimer function is being used properly. Also, I have no idea how to create a toggle to exit the script. Thanks in advance

Here's what I have so far:

```
x := 600
y := 850
a := 850
b := 850

^j:: {
Loop {
 {
   SetTimer, Clicker, 300000
   Clicker:
      mouseclick, left, %x%, %y%, 1, 0
      mouseclick, left, %a%, %b%, 1000, 0
   return
 }
return
}
return
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x := 600
y := 850
a := 850
b := 850

^j:: ; Cntrl j, To start the timer
   SetTimer, Clicker, 300000
Return
^+j:: ; Shift Cntrl j, To stop the timer
   SetTimer, Clicker, Off
Return

Clicker:
      mouseclick, left, %x%, %y%, 1, 0
      mouseclick, left, %a%, %b%, 1000, 0
Return
```

I didn't test the answer, just wrote it from memory.

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet, so here's an answer!
Doesn't Roberts code just produce one click? Like semi-automatic?
Here's what I would have done. I'm far from an expert though, and it isn't tested.

```
x := 600
y := 850
a := 850
b := 850

^j::
Clicker:
mouseclick, left, %x%, %y%, 1, 0
mouseclick, left, %a%, %b%, 1000, 0
SetTimer, Clicker, 300000
return

^+j::
SetTimer, Clicker, Off
return
```